# How to work a file on another file without using require() or require_once() functions in php?

Tags: php, wamp

I am seeking a solution to execute a file on another file without using `require()` or `require_once()` functions in php. Such as I want to run some codes which are in `functions.php` on another file `index.php` file. I am using wamp server and my folder is as bellow...

`projects/index.php` and`projects/functions.php`. I had a solution of that job done. I had edited the `php.ini` file and that was `auto_prepend_file = "C:\wamp\www\projects\\functions.php"`. But this is not working. I do not know why this is happening.

Comment: Just use `require` dont go out of your way to make your code harder to understand. Perhaps its time to consider an OO approach, with a class autoloader

Comment: Why exactly do you think you need this to begin with? What exactly is "not working" about `auto_prepend_file`? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Can you give an idea of why you are trying to avoid using require? It seems like there is probably a better way to solve whatever problem there is.

Comment: I want just to execute functions of `functions.php` in index.php. And I know `_autolaod` function can be used if I go through OOP way. But I want it just simple to be done. Please give me a solution. If without using  `auto_prepend_file`, this job can be done, then you can give me solutions. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, `require 'functions.php` seems pretty simple already.

Comment: Get used to the idea that *explicit is better than implicit*. If your file depends on another file, **it's best to explicitly declare this dependency inside the file itself** using a `require_once`. It simplifies dependency management and avoids problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try using composer to autoload you classes

To get started with composer visit: https://getcomposer.org/

You can read the documentation here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

If you are more of a visual learner you can see this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGSerlMoIrY) to get you started.